# How do I use symphony to target a specific powermail form in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x, powermail

On a `TYPO3 10.x` installation, I have a `Powermail 8.x` form with ID `3`, within this form are multiple fieldsets. On one of these fieldsets with ID `7` I would like to wrap these fields into columns which works fine *without* the Symfony expression.

Is it possible to specifically target `fieldset 7` using Typoscript? I've tried many variations of the following concept, but I cannot get it to work.

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_powermail_pi1']['form']['fieldset'] == 7]
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup {
        styles {
            numberOfColumns = 2
            framework {
                rowClasses = row
            }
        }
    }
[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, I'm pretty sure, it's the wrong operator...

The Comparison Operator for equality is `==`, not a single `=`.

[The Expression Syntax - Comparison Operator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#comparison-operators)

**Update:**

I didn't get a test instance of TYPO3 v10 with Powermail Multistep up and running quickly. So, I couldn't try it... But Alex (maintainer of EXT:powermail) confirmed on twitter that the [multistep function is based purely on JavaScript](https://twitter.com/einpraegsam/status/1423742329622605829).

A server-side query between the steps is therefore impossible. So, it's not the symfony expression that does not fit, but the logic behind your use-case. The condition would apply, but it never receives this GET/POST parameter.

Comment: Well spotted, unfortunately that was not the solution as to why the expression is not working.

Comment: Are you sure, there's (still) this parameter/field? All I can find with "step" in powermail's sources is a Viewhelper for building a CSS classname... Please have a look in your HTTP-request.